# Dealing with char values over 127 in C

Tags: c, character-encoding, char

I'm quite new to C programming, and I have some problems trying to assign a value over 127 (0x7F) in a char array. In my program, I work with generic binary data and I don't face any problem printing a previously acquired byte stream (e.g. with fopen or fgets, then processed with some bitwise operations) as %c or %d.
But if I try to print a character from its numerical value like this:

```
printf("%c\n", 128);
```

it just prints FFFD (the replacement character).
Here is another example:

```
char abc[] = {126, 128, '\0'}; // Manually assigning values
printf("%c", abc[0]); // Prints "~", as expected
printf("%c", 121); // Prints "y"
pritf("%c", abc[1]; // Should print "€", I think, but I get "�"
```

I'm a bit confused since I can just print every character below 128 in these ways.
The reason I'm asking this, is because I need to generate a (pseudo)random byte sequence using the rand() function.
Here is an example:

```
char abc[10];
srand(time(NULL));
abc[0] = rand() % 256; // Gives something between 00:FF ...
printf("%c", abc[0]); // ... but I get "�"
```

If this is of any help, the source code is encoded in UTF-8, but changing encoding doesn't have any effect.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *`printf("%c\n", 128);` just returns `FFFD` (the replacement character).* Function `printf` returns the number of characters printed.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, I meant it prints the replacement character on the screen, not as a return value. Edited

Comment: Something else, outside your program, must be generating that "replacement character". When I run your program it prints a character with the value `0x80`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, a `char` is a different type than `unsigned char` and `signed char`.  It has the range `CHAR_MIN` to `CHAR_MAX`.  Yet it has the same range as one of `unsigned char`/`signed char`.  Typically these are 8-bit types, but could be more. See `CHAR_BIT`.  So the typical range is `[0 to 255]` or `[-128 to 127]`

If `char` is unsigned, `abc[1] = 128` is fine.  If `char` is signed, `abc[1] = 128` is implementation-defined (see below).  The typical I-D is the `abc[1]` will have the value of `-128`.

`printf("%c\n", 128);` will send the `int` value 128 to `printf()`.  The `"%c"` will cast that value to an `unsigned char`.  So far no problems.  What appears on the output depends on how the output device handles code 128.  Perhaps `Ç`, perhaps something else.

`printf("%c", abc[1];` will send 128 or is I-D.  If I-D and `-128` was sent, then casting -128 to `unsigned char` is 128 and again the code for 128 is printed.

If the output device is expecting UTF8 sequences, a UTF8 sequence beginning with code 128 is invalid (it is an unexpected continuation byte) and many such systems will print the replacement character which is unicode  FFFD.

---

Converting a value outside the range of of a *signed* `char` to `char` invokes:

> the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised. C11dr §6.3.1.3 3

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that the terminal was printing `FFFD` because it was invalid UTF-8, while forcing the output to e.g. ISO-8859-1 gives the expected results, like @KeithThompson guessed. Besides that, I was quite unaware of the UB of `signed char` with >127, as my system apparently casts `char` to the right type, but that's not a thing I should rely on.

Comment: I think it's "implementation-defined behavior" rather than "undefined behavior".   CISO/IEC9899:201x 6.3.1.3.3: "Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy Agreed. Answer amended.

Comment: pritf("%c", abc[1]; - misprint near pritf

Comment: @SetiVolkylany Edited

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me tell you, signed-ness of a `char` is implementation defined.

If you have to deal with `char` values over 127, you can use `unsigned char`. It can handle 0-255.

Also, you should be using `%hhu` format specifier to print the value of an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with bytes, use `unsigned char` instead of `char` for your datatypes.

With regard to printing, you can print the bytes in hex instead of decimal or as characters:

```
printf("%02X", abc[0]);
```

You probably don't want to print these bytes as characters, as you'll most likely be dealing with UTF-8 character encoding which doesn't seem to be what you're looking for.